# Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions of an Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Suppose I am given two orthonormal vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ which constitute a base of a two-dimensional space. Suppose also that an operator $T$ defined on this space is satisfying some equations of the form: $Tv_1=av_2+bv_2$ and $Tv_2=cv_1+dv_2$. How do I calculate the eigenvalues and the orthonormal eigenfunctions of $T$?

Comment: @ Andrew I'm not sure what you mean under _orthonormal eigenfunctions_.  Could you, please, explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that basis the matrix corresponding to $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$.
To see this, I encourage you to see the definition of a matrix of an operator in a given basis.
The eigenvalues and eigenfunctions in this basis can be found by the usual means for matrices.
In the end you just need to interpret $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ as $xv_1+yv_2$.

Comment: So, calculating the eigenfunctions is all about expressing the eigenvectors in a more 'analytic' form like the one you described?

Comment: @AndrewTzevas In this case, yes. When the dimension is low and everything is explicit, this is often the best approach. (Did you notice that you now have the [privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to vote?)

Answer (score 1):

This is a finite dimensional question, so you may write the operator in matrix form (using the basis $v_1,v_2$) as 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\b&d \end{bmatrix}
$$
then solve for the roots of characteristic polynomial to find eigenvalues $\lambda$ (there may be none, one, or two depending on what field you are over!) solving
$$
\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+\det(T)=0
$$
If you get an eigenvalue $\lambda$, you find eigenvectors by examining 
$$
\ker\left(\begin{bmatrix}a-\lambda&c\\b&d-\lambda \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$